# Bootstrap nav not vertically aligned and toggle doesn't push div down

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

Long time free user, first time signing up and posting so forgive me if I miss out some info.

I am currently using the twitter bootstrap framework to create a site, but am having considerable trouble with the navigation.

I want the navigation to float to the right, which is working fine, but I can't seem to get the text to vertically align properly. For some reason, the toggle button, when is mobile device view is also a bit buggy in the fact that it doesn't push the rest of the content down, but hovers over the top.

Further to this, I would like the mobile device view to have a left defined menu, as opposed to the right floating nav for the desktop version.

Code as follows:

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="mhNavigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.jpg" alt="MH Elite Logo" id="logo"></a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="mhNavbar">
                    <li class="mhActive"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#fitnesscentre">FITNESS CENTRE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#transformations">TRANSFORMATIONS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#timetable">TIMETABLE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!--.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: black;
}
.navbar-collapse.in,
.navbar-collapse.collapsing {
  border-top: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
#mhNavigation {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: black !important;
  border-bottom: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#mhNavigation #logo {
  width: 5em;
}
#mhNavigation #mhNavbar {
  float: right;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#mhNavigation #mhNavbar li {
  min-height: 5em;
}
#mhNavigation #mhNavbar li a {
  font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: none;
  padding-top: 0;
}
#mhNavigation #mhNavbar li a:hover {
  color: #ca090b;
}
#mhNavigation #mhNavbar .mhActive {
  background: none !important;
}
#mhNavigation #mhNavbar .mhActive a {
  color: #ca090b !important;
  text-shadow: none;
}
```

FIDDLE/BOOTPLY:

http://www.bootply.com/6eI3s3aHCg

Comment: You need to post your compiled LESS so people have your CSS to work with.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or bootply so we can see it in action

Comment: fiddle link added. Doesn't quite pull down the fonts, but it shows the functionality.

Comment: Can anybody help at all? :(

Comment: Still in need of some assistance with this please

Comment: Hi all, I have still not managed to solve this problem. Any help would be greatly, greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Your custom styles are troubling the alignment. what i see is ' padding-top: 0;' on element "#mhNavigation #mhNavbar li a" is the cause. pls try removing it.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this out, mostly. Bootstrap already has a navbar-right class that I can apply to the <ul> tag that will float the content to the right on a desktop screen, but stacks it nicely with a left orientation when on mobile devices.

Now to figure out how to 'push' the content down on a toggle, but that is less important.